# USB drive not mounting on Kubuntu; mounts on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: boot, mount, kubuntu, usb-drive

I'm running Kubuntu 32bit (not sure which version). I want go back to having Ubuntu 14.04 which I have on my USB drive but it isn't mounting it.
I have tried this but but it doesn't find anything:

`sudo mount -o rw /dev/sdb1 /mnt`

I tried mounting it on my girlfriend's computer running Ubuntu 14.04 and it worked like a charm there.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What does dmesg say when you plug it in (type `dmesg` in terminal - you'll get screens of text, the last few lines are the relevant bit, if you've just plugged it in)?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the disk utility and then see if your drive is showing up

```
  sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

if the drive shows up you should be able to mount it without problem

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that your usb device is recognized as sdb1, this could be done my the command

```
dmesg
```

you will receive the following output near end (over here my usb is recognized as sdb1)

[67846.595889]  sdb: sdb1

[67846.600396] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

I would prefer you to make your own directory to mount your usb.
so type the command (after this your will see an folder created in your computer)

```
mkdir anyName
```

Then mount your usb using the command

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /anyName
```

p.s

You can also check whether your computer is recognizing your usb or not by the command

```
lsusb
```

this should provide you with your USB details along with its vendor.